# Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined - discord js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Пишу бота для дискорда, но при вводе команды "!crypto" выводит в консоль это - "Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined"

```
const {
    Client,
    Message,
    MessageEmbed
} = require('discord.js');
const axios = require('axios');


module.exports = {
    name: 'crypto',
    aliases: [],
    description: '',
    usage: '',
    /** 
     * @param {Client} client 
     * @param {Message} message 
     * @param {String[]} args
     */

    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        const btcPrice = axios.get('https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/kraken/btcusd/price').then((res) => {
            return res.data.result.price;
        });
        const ethPrice = axios.get('https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/kraken/ethusd/price').then((res) => {
            return res.data.result.price;
        });
        const ltcPrice = axios.get('https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/kraken/ltcusd/price').then((res) => {
            return res.data.result.price;
        });
        const bchPrice = axios.get('https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/kraken/bchusd/price').then((res) => {
            return res.data.result.price;
        });
        const adaPrice = axios.get('https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/kraken/adausd/price').then((res) => {
            return res.data.result.price;
        });
        const dogePrice = axios.get('https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/kraken/dogeusd/price').then((res) => {
            return res.data.result.price;
        });

        const emoji = ':dollar:';

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Current crypto prices.')
            .addFields({
                name: 'BTC',
                value: `${emoji} ${btcPrice}`,
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: 'ETH',
                value: `${emoji} ${ethPrice}`,
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: 'LTC',
                value: `${emoji} ${ltcPrice}`,
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: 'BCH',
                value: `${emoji} ${bchPrice}`,
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: 'ADA',
                value: `${emoji} ${adaPrice}`,
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: 'DOGE',
                value: `${emoji} ${dogePrice}`,
                inline: true
            }, )
            .setColor('GREEN')
            .setTimestamp();

        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
};
```

заранее спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Попробуйте message с большой буквы написать.

Comment: Теперь send of undefined )

Answer (score 0):

В вашем примере не используются Client и Message. Также непонятно где используется функция run и что именно в неё приходит.

По документации

```
'use strict';

/**
 * A ping pong bot, whenever you send "ping", it replies "pong".
 */

// Import the discord.js module
const Discord = require('discord.js');

// Create an instance of a Discord client
const client = new Discord.Client();

/**
 * The ready event is vital, it means that only _after_ this will your bot start reacting to information
 * received from Discord
 */
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('I am ready!');
});

// Create an event listener for messages
client.on('message', message => {
  // If the message is "ping"
  if (message.content === 'ping') {
    // Send "pong" to the same channel
    message.channel.send('pong');
  }
});

// Log our bot in using the token from https://discord.com/developers/applications
client.login('your token here');
```

Чтобы использовать message необходимо создать инстанс client. Вызывать у него метод `on('message', function)` и только потом уже отсылать `message.channel.send('')`